# After Updating Rstudio 1.1.383 I have errors with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio

I just updated RStudio from version 0.99.896 to 1.1.383 (the latest) working on Ubuntu 16.4.

Before to update, I wrote a script of analysis in which I plot an interpolation of a data set using `akima` and `ggplot2`.

this is the script:

```
require(akima) #this package interpolate values
require(ggplot2)
Space1 <- subset(x = ChlaMD2, Depth <= 14 & !(Station %in% c("P10","P11","P12c"))
          & Class_size == 0.3) 
Space2 <- subset(x = ChlaMD2, Depth <= 14 & Station %in% c("P10","P11")
                 & Class_size == 0.3 & Time == "D") 
Space <- rbind(Space1,Space2)
duplicated(Space)
attach(Space)

fld <- with(Space, interp(x = Longitud.E., y = Latitude.S., z = Chla2017_mean,duplicate = "mean"))
gdat <- interp2xyz(fld, data.frame=TRUE)

ggplot(gdat) + 
  aes(x = x, y = y, z = z, fill = z) + 
  geom_tile() + 
  #coord_equal() +
  geom_contour(color = "white", alpha = 0.5) + 
  scale_fill_distiller(palette="Spectral", na.value="white",limits=c(0,0.35)) + 
  scale_y_reverse()+
  theme_bw()+
  ggtitle("Chlorophyll-a (class size 0.3-2.7 um)")+
  ylab("Latitude S") + xlab("Longitude E")+
  labs(fill = "Chl-a (mg/m3)")+
  geom_point(data = Space, mapping =  aes(Longitud.E.,Latitude.S.),shape=1)
```

It worked really well, but after the updating I have this error massage:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'z' not found
```

these are the structures of gdat and fld:

```
str(gdat)
'data.frame':   1600 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ x: num  37.3 37.3 37.4 37.4 37.4 ...
 $ y: num  45.7 45.7 45.7 45.7 45.7 ...
 $ z: num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...

> str(fld)
List of 3
 $ x: num [1:40] 37.3 37.3 37.4 37.4 37.4 ...
 $ y: num [1:40] 45.7 45.8 45.8 45.9 45.9 ...
 $ z: num [1:40, 1:40] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

Here as an example a subtable of my dataset that I called ChlaMD2

```
> dput(ChlaMD2)
structure(list(Station = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 8L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
15L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 
22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 
23L, 23L, 19L), .Label = c("C12", "C23", "C27", "C30", "C35", 
"C53", "C57", "D1", "D11", "D12", "D2", "D3", "D4", "D5", "D6", 
"D7", "D8", "D9", "H1", "H13", "H17", "H18", "H19", "H2", "H20", 
"H21", "H3", "H4", "H5", "H7", "P10", "P11", "P12", "P12c"), class = "factor"), 
    Time = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("", "D", "N"), class = "factor"), 
    Class_size = c(0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 
    0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 
    0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 25, 25, 25, 
    25, 25, 25, 2.7, 2.7, 2.7, 2.7, 2.7, 2.7, 0.3, 0.3, 25, 25, 
    2.7, 2.7, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 
    25, 2.7, 2.7, 2.7, 2.7, 2.7, 2.7, 0.3, 0.3, 0.7, 25, 25, 
    2.7, 2.7, 0.3), Depth = c(1, 1, 10, 10, 40, 10, 10, 10, 50, 
    10.1, 25.4, 10, 10.5, 10, 10, 35, 10, 15, 15, 10, 107, 9.8, 
    10, 10, 10, 100, 150, 30, 40, 60, 10, 100, 150, 30, 40, 60, 
    10, 100, 150, 30, 40, 60, 10, 60, 10, 60, 10, 60, 10, 100, 
    20, 40, 60, 80, 10, 100, 20, 40, 60, 80, 10, 100, 20, 40, 
    60, 80, 10, 50, 10, 10, 50, 10, 50, 30), Latitude.S. = c(46.7861666666667, 
    46.8812166666667, 46.7836333333333, 46.8828666666667, 46.7471666666667, 
    46.9049166666667, 47.021, 46.6074, 46.6074, 46.8082333333333, 
    46.8082333333333, 46.80335, 46.7286833333333, 46.7286833333333, 
    46.8039666666667, 46.8039666666667, 46.80175, 47.80175, 48.80175, 
    46.8032166666667, 46.8032166666667, 46.7251666666667, 46.85855, 
    46.8078333333333, 46.7498, 46.7498, 46.7498, 46.7498, 46.7498, 
    46.7498, 46.7498, 46.7498, 46.7498, 46.7498, 46.7498, 46.7498, 
    46.7498, 46.7498, 46.7498, 46.7498, 46.7498, 46.7498, 46.74985, 
    46.74985, 46.74985, 46.74985, 46.74985, 46.74985, 46.74985, 
    46.74985, 46.74985, 46.74985, 46.74985, 46.74985, 46.74985, 
    46.74985, 46.74985, 46.74985, 46.74985, 46.74985, 46.74985, 
    46.74985, 46.74985, 46.74985, 46.74985, 46.74985, 46.74985, 
    46.74985, 46.74985, 46.74985, 46.74985, 46.74985, 46.74985, 
    45.7494), Longitud.E. = c(37.8826666666667, 37.8811166666667, 
    38.0012833333333, 37.91525, 37.799, 37.5724833333333, 37.942, 
    37.9704, 37.9704, 38.0699666666667, 38.0699666666667, 37.98505, 
    37.7509666666667, 37.7509666666667, 37.9852, 37.9852, 37.8366166666667, 
    38.8366166666667, 39.8366166666667, 37.9857833333333, 37.9857833333333, 
    38.07365, 38.0585833333333, 38.0727, 38.5003666666667, 38.5003666666667, 
    38.5003666666667, 38.5003666666667, 38.5003666666667, 38.5003666666667, 
    38.5003666666667, 38.5003666666667, 38.5003666666667, 38.5003666666667, 
    38.5003666666667, 38.5003666666667, 38.5003666666667, 38.5003666666667, 
    38.5003666666667, 38.5003666666667, 38.5003666666667, 38.5003666666667, 
    38.3001666666667, 38.3001666666667, 38.3001666666667, 38.3001666666667, 
    38.3001666666667, 38.3001666666667, 38.1007, 38.1007, 38.1007, 
    38.1007, 38.1007, 38.1007, 38.1007, 38.1007, 38.1007, 38.1007, 
    38.1007, 38.1007, 38.1007, 38.1007, 38.1007, 38.1007, 38.1007, 
    38.1007, 37.9009666666667, 37.9009666666667, 37.9009666666667, 
    37.9009666666667, 37.9009666666667, 37.9009666666667, 37.9009666666667, 
    37.2994833333333), Chla2017_mean = c(-0.946057215301194, 
    -0.735763592835187, -0.721930224211009, -0.743435200089837, 
    -1.02003987926121, -0.738912060933631, -0.685963597586669, 
    -0.997636902853672, -0.643630322972336, -0.669377265328764, 
    -0.664963978099764, -0.912380457471698, -0.654771449880747, 
    -0.658883141830635, -0.333377057394302, -0.834435774509827, 
    -0.608164121834402, -0.601054836622574, -0.601054836622574, 
    -0.433924828117425, -0.423546688240005, -0.674419537322733, 
    -0.750411161442486, -0.725080930111579, -0.935910556294799, 
    -0.817942131498285, -1.02383834665726, -0.892403896151859, 
    -0.808467536615044, -0.884840160205845, -1.0603345408323, 
    -1.07867052090535, -1.11040448340463, -1.09645994731746, 
    -1.06683594257792, -1.07149832401568, -1.00312051998841, 
    -0.892390049851206, -1.0156562515399, -0.845436000058676, 
    -0.77307928664173, -0.898018165946667, -0.848289249417617, 
    -0.810493908599841, -1.09301597219965, -1.10655481387971, 
    -0.85745513293466, -0.876433420431031, -0.661357685769219, 
    -0.86379511602107, -0.671973895984953, -0.612517223135917, 
    -0.53238050140151, -0.766900709336143, -1.07529825124183, 
    -1.11868087013396, -1.09598460061627, -1.0797581766586, -1.09630430291743, 
    -1.10204233962275, -0.773288219842876, -0.897549491056236, 
    -0.781499768825993, -0.644915965716444, -0.612259094442557, 
    -0.827935663448589, -0.410489183767067, -0.487960331090299, 
    -0.439197104297121, -1.06520799675057, -1.08484214393861, 
    -0.548500319979572, -0.559953402295738, -0.62854993920894
    )), .Names = c("Station", "Time", "Class_size", "Depth", 
"Latitude.S.", "Longitud.E.", "Chla2017_mean"), row.names = c(NA, 
74L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I hope you will understand if I don't provide my data as an example. 
I just interpolated a data frame of three columns (x, y, z) in which x and y are coordinates and y is the parameter. With the interpolation, some NAs have been created, for good reasons of the dataset.

Comment: If we can't reproduce your data and error, we cannot help. The code works fine with example dataframe with xyz columns, try: `gdat <- data.frame(x = runif(10),
                   y = runif(10),
                   z = runif(10));

ggplot(gdat) + 
  aes(x = x, y = y, z = z, fill = z) + 
  geom_tile()
`

Comment: Thank you, you are right. But my case is different (I do not know why). So I added an example

Comment: Change the last line to this: `geom_point(data = Space, mapping =  aes(Longitud.E., Latitude.S.),shape=1, inherit.aes = FALSE`

Comment: It works, Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*geom_point* on the last line is inheriting aes from first aes which has *z* as fill. We need to use `inherit.aes = FALSE`:

```
ggplot(gdat) + 
  aes(x = x, y = y, z = z, fill = z) + 
  geom_tile() + 
  geom_contour(color = "white", alpha = 0.5) + 
  geom_point(data = Space, mapping = aes(Longitud.E., Latitude.S.),
             shape = 1, inherit.aes = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Spectral", na.value = "white") + 
  scale_y_reverse() +
  theme_bw() +
  ggtitle("Chlorophyll-a (class size 0.3-2.7 um)") +
  ylab("Latitude S") + xlab("Longitude E") +
  labs(fill = "Chl-a (mg/m3)")
```

Minor changes to your code:

- I prefer geoms first then scale, theme, labs, etc.
- I removed the limits in *scale_fill_distiller*

[image]